# .gitignore put in /home does not ignore files in /home/username

Tags: git

I know this is a bad practice but I changed the permission of `/home` and put a `.gitignore` there (I have a weird use case, let's keep it at that for now, will discuss more about it in the **P.S.**).

My `.gitignore` looks like:

```
/*
!/.gitignore

!/ismail/
/ismail/*

!/ismail/.zshrc

!/ismail/.searchmonkey/
/ismail/.searchmonkey/*
!/ismail/.searchmonkey/*

!/ismail/.config/
/ismail/.config/*

!/ismail/.config/user-dirs.dirs

!/ismail/.config/alacritty/
/ismail/.config/alacritty/*
!/ismail/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
```

The thing is this `.gitignore` does not work in `/home` , but works when I put it in `/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git`.

The permission of both directories:

```
/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git:master+%
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 4 ismail ismail 4096 Jun  6 12:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ismail ismail 4096 Jun  6 12:24 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ismail ismail  296 Jun  6 12:39 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 4 ismail ismail 4096 Jun  6 12:25 ismail

/home:master*+% ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  4 ismail ismail 4096 Jun  6 12:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   4096 May 31 22:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ismail ismail 2284 Jun  6 12:40 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 23 ismail ismail 4096 Jun  6 12:57 ismail
```

**P.S.** Please feel free to give any suggestion that meet my use case. My use case is, I track dotfiles of two linux distros. There are some common files and there are some distro specific files. So, my bare repos look like `dotfiles_bare_repo_common`, `dotfiles_bare_repo_mint`, `dotfiles_bare_repo_zorin`. So, for a given time, I need to put two `.gitignore` in `/home/ismail` (`dotfiles_bare_repo_common` and `dotfiles_bare_repo_mint` or `dotfiles_bare_repo_common`, `dotfiles_bare_repo_zorin`), which is not an option. So, I decided to move one step up and put common `.gitignore` in `/home` and distro specific `.gitignore` in `/home/ismail`, to maintain two `.gitignore` for same directory (`.git/info/exclude` does not work for me, as I need to push or clone the repos). I have also checked [Can you set multiple gitignore files, in the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161069/can-you-set-multiple-gitignore-files-in-the-same-directory) and [Are multiple `.gitignore`s frowned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305869/are-multiple-gitignores-frowned-on). These also does not fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is this .gitignore does not work in /home , but works when I put it in `/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git`.

That is because you are using "anchored" rules (my term for "rules starting with `/`"): the anchor "`/`" means [the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)... inside a Git repository.
And `/home` is not the inside a Git repository.

There is no native solution, but possible workarounds:

- I would consider symlinks from each repository to the relevant `.gitignore`.
- Or a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005830/6309) to generate the right `.gitignore` depending on the repository.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, `And /home is not the inside a Git repository.` I did not understand.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail Unless you did a `git init .` directly in `/home` (which is not a good practice), then `/home` is not part of a Git repository.

Comment: I have done `git --git-dir=/media/ismail/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup/ --work-tree=/home`. In both cases though there is not a `.git` directory, they are part of git. In one case my `.gitignore` works, in another case it does not work.

Comment: I mean the `"anchored" rule` work when I have `git --git-dir=/media/ismail/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup/ --work-tree=/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git` but does not work when I have `git --git-dir=/media/ismail/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup/ --work-tree=/home`

Comment: @AhmadIsmail I would recommend setting environment variable `GIT_WORK_TREE` and |GIT_DIR` to test if gitignore works better then. Use `git check-ignore -v`

Comment: `GIT_WORK_TREE` & `GIT_DIR` also does not work.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail That is expected, considering the `.gitignore` file is outside the designated worktree (like `/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git`). Hence my suggestion for symlink from `/home/ismail/Desktop/test-git/.gitignore` to `/home/.gitignore`.